# Spring Batch SplitBuilder does not execute the starting flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I'm using the Spring Batch (2.2.6.RELEASE) `FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder` to declare a flow in a Java Config class, which executes 3 subflows in parallel:

```
@Bean
public SimpleFlow mainFlow() {
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("Main Flow")
            .start(flow1())
            .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .add(flow2(), flow3())
            .build();
}
```

This syntax comes from [spring-batch `FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder` javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/builder/FlowBuilder.SplitBuilder.html).

But then, `flow1` is never executed; only `flow2` and `flow3` are executed.

It looks like a bug to me... What do you think?

A junit test can be found in class `ParallelFlowsJobConfigTest` on this github repository: https://github.com/galak75/spring-batch-labs

Comment: Seems to be related to a newly resolved [BATCH-2346](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2346) issue. I'll have to run my tests with Spring Batch 3.0.4 release.

Comment: Spring Batch 3.0.4 is not yet released so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by [BATCH-2346](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2346), delivered in Spring Batch 3.0.4 release.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
@Bean
public SimpleFlow mainFlow() {
    SimpleFlow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("Split Flow")
        .split(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
        .add(flow2(), flow3())
        .build();
    return new FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("Main Flow")
        .start(flow1())
        .next(splitFlow)
        .end();
}
```

The important detail is the "next(...)" and the fact that slit should be in its own sub-flow.

Comment: Are the 3 subflows executed in parallel with this configuration?

Comment: Arg. No! I thought you were trying to execute flow1, and then flow2 + 3